# send post with list of id from html table for rows with checkbox property select using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this table that is generated dynamically

[image: HTML code for table]

[image: HTML table]

I want to POST the list of id numbers of rows with selected checkbox.

I was able to get td elements selected using

```
        $('form#submit').submit(function(event) {
            $('#record_id tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').find('td').each(function() {
                console.log(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
```

I don't know how to build the list of id to send in POST.

Answer (score 0):

I include table class to record_id table and use the following jquery code

```
        $('form#submit').submit(function(event) {
            var values = [];
            $('table > tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                values.push(this.name);
            });
            console.log(values);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/systemlog",
                // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
                data: JSON.stringify({ logs: values }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });
            return false;
        });
```

[image]